# Transferring files between two network switches

Tags: scp

I am trying to transfer a file between two network switches.

Topology:

SwitchA------SwitchB (10.219.20.209)

Below are the steps I tried:

1. Generated the public ssh-key on SwitchA using this command -

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. Copied the newly generated key from SwitchA to SwitchB using this command -

   `scp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@10.219.20.209:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
3. Tried transferring the file now, however its still asking for the credentials.

   `root@RE:0% scp test.sh root@10.219.20.209:/tmp/`
   `Password:`

Please suggest how I can achieve the file transfers without using a password.

Comment: You could use netcat. Strangely my comment has been deleted by someone.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? Do you want to copy files from SwitchA to SwitchB without entering a password? Or do you think the file copied in step 2 was not successfully copied for some other reason?

Comment: Try putting the contents of id_rsa.pub into /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, not /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

Comment: @Wieland I am trying to transfer files from SwitchA to SwitchB without entering a password. In Step2 I confirm that the public which got generated on SwitchA, successfully copied to SwitchB which should allow passwordless file transfer. But when I tried to do the transfer from SwitchA to SwitchB, Its asking for the password.

Comment: @jsbillings I only see the below list in my switch.
root@jtac-qfx5100-24q-2p-r2228:RE:0% cd /root/.ssh

id_rsa.pub
known_hosts
ssh_host_ecdsa_key -> /config/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub -> /config/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
ssh_host_ed25519_key -> /config/ssh_host_ed25519_key
ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub -> /config/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
ssh_host_rsa_key -> /config/ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh_host_rsa_key.pub -> /config/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

Comment: You will have to create a new file called /root/.ssh/authorized_keys.  That's how PubkeyAuthentication works, the server on the remote side has the pubkey from the client side in the user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: Although I just realized you said these are *switches*.  What kind of switch is it?

Comment: @jsbillings thanks for your inputs. they are juniper networks QFX5100 platform running JUNOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
set arg2 [lindex $argv 1]
set DATE [exec date +%Y_%m_%d-%H.%M.%S]

spawn echo $DATE
spawn ssh $arg1 -l root

expect {   
          "*(yes/no)*"  { send "yes\r" }
          "Password:"   { send "Juniper\r" }
}
expect {
         "Password:"   { send "Juniper\r" }
         "*@*" {send " \r" }
}
set FILE $arg2 
append FILE "_"
append FILE $DATE

send "cd /var/tmp/; cp $arg2 $FILE ; echo \"\" > NH-HALP.log \r"
expect  "*@*"
send "scp \"$FILE\" root@10.219.43.163:/var/tmp/\r" 
expect {
          "*(yes/no)*"  { send "yes\r" }
          "Password:"   { send "Juniper\r" }
}
expect {
         "Password:"   { send "Juniper\r" }
         "*@*" {send " \r" }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that with Juniper switches, there is a unique syntax for [configuring authentication](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/authentication-edit-system-login.html).

Here is the syntax:

```
authentication {
(encrypted-password "password" | plain-text-password);
load-key-file URL filename;
no-public-keys;
ssh-dsa "public-key";
ssh-ecdsa "public-key";
ssh-rsa "public-key";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 2: use `ssh-copy-id root@10.219.20.209`

Also, verify the rights of `/root/.ssh` on 10.219.20.209. They must be `drwx------`.